Ubuntu 24.04 docker command not working without sudo
I have upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 and docker ps not returing any error or result. Before in 22.04 it was working perfectly. Now it just stuck at command. No Timeout, no Eerror.
But with sudo it works with sudo. My user is in already in docker group. Everything seems on place.

What does ls -l /var/run/docker.sock show?

╰─ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Sen 25 13:34 /var/run/docker.sock

Try setting your docker context to the default:
docker context use default

You can also take a look at which contexts you have
docker context ls

Other than that, I would try to run a container without the sudo command and then check the running containers without sudo. Could be some discrepancy in how the files are stored when executing it with and without root privileges.

bro you are my hero thanks :)

I had installed docker-desktop for my ubuntu. And it added new context and my context was not the default one. I changed it to default context and everything worked again :)

Glad that it worked, please mark it as the "Accepted answer" :)

From Linux post-installation steps for Docker Engine
Check that docker group exists:
getent group docker

If it doesn't exist, create it:
sudo groupadd docker

Add your user to the docker group:
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

The changes are active when you have logged out and logged in again, or executed the command:
newgrp docker

Now try without sudo:
docker run hello-world


No it does not work like that. It is been already added to the group and everything was okay and now my user is in docker group. Problem seems in another place
